# Sending files along with data(token) to http server without specifying file name

Tags: c#, http

I'm creating a FileSystemWatcher in windows application using c# that will send the latest file to HTTP server.

1) In this FileSystemWatcher, after clicking on the browse button the user has the choice to select the folder/directory(where the latest files will be downloaded).

2) After clicking on the Monitor button, it'll monitor for new file that are downloaded from internet or mailbox. When user downloads any new file, it'll trigger an event(i.e., message box specifying the FileName with two buttons i.e., YES and NO).

3)Along with this,it'll also be showing a complete filepath of the latest file in the file system watcher.

4) The latest file will come in the directory(here directory will be according to the user's choice) and will send those files along with data to http server.

My question is that how can i send those files(i.e., latest files that are downloaded from internet) along with some data (after clicking on YES button from the message box) to http server without specifying the file path.

I'm able to send files by specifying the complete filepath from my local. But in this case, the filepath may be different according to user's choice.After clicking on YES button,how can i send the latest file(i.e., downloaded from internet or mailbox) along with some token or data to HTTP server in c#. I'm not able to to understand that how it'll pick the file that is shown in the messagebox.

This is my code:-

```
      //This is FileSystemWatcher Created Event 
    private void fileWatcher_Created(object sender,System.IO. FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text += e.ChangeType + ": " + e.FullPath + "\r\n";
        textBox3.Focus();
        textBox3.Select(textBox3.TextLength, 0);
        textBox3.ScrollToCaret();
     }

   //This is FileSystemWatcher Renamed_1Created Event 
     private void fileWatcher_Renamed_1(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
       // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        textBox3.Text += e.ChangeType + ": " + e.FullPath+ "\r\n";
        textBox3.Focus();
        textBox3.Select(textBox3.TextLength, 0);
        textBox3.ScrollToCaret();
      try
           {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;


            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "fileName:-" + e.Name, "New File", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
               {
                     WebClient client = new WebClient();
                     string myFile = @"FilePath";
                     client.UploadFile("url", "POST", myFile);
                     MessageBox.Show("Sent");
                     client.Dispose();

                //If user click NO button

                    if (result == DialogResult.No)
                 {
                        Close();
                 }
              }
            }

        finally
        {
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
     }

    //This is textBox of FileSystemWatcher where the filename and file path will be shown 
     private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         textBox3.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
     }

    //This is monitor button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileWatcher.Path = @textBox1.Text;
        fileWatcher.Filter = textBox2.Text;
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = checkBox1.Checked;
       // fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        button1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }

    //This is the stop button
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        button2.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }

    //This is Browse button
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;

        // Create a new instance of FolderBrowserDialog.
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();


        // A new folder button will display in FolderBrowserDialog.
        folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        //Show FolderBrowserDialog
        DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            //Show selected folder path in textbox1.
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;

            //Browsing start from root folder.
            Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;

        }
    }
```

Please help me through this.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Your question is hard to understand and probably needs some more tags, e.g. what is the programming language of your sample code at all?

Comment: Thanks @StefanHegny. Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Your actual question is about sending the files via http, right? The file system watcher works, right? In that case the file system watcher actually has not much to do with the question. The question is about somehow sending "files via http without specifying the full path"? The upload code via http is in your code snippet. Does it function correctly like that? What exactly is the problem with it? In which scenario don't you have the full file path...?

Comment: Yes, the upload code function works correctly. But for that i've to write a complete path of the filename from my local. Here, the messagebox will trigger each time when a new file will come in the directory. The exact problem is to send that most new file from the messagebox via http.